# Why does $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1000 \sqrt n}$ diverge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{1000 \sqrt n}$

Why does it diverge?

Comment: Do you know $\sum 1/n^p$ diverges if $p<1$?

Comment: In the same way that $\sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{1}{n}$ diverges, your sum also diverges. Using the integral test, you can see that any series with summand $\frac{1}{n^p}$ diverges for $p<1$. The constant doesn't affect the divergence or convergence of the series.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because
$$\frac{1}{1000}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt n}\gt\frac{1}{1000}\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{n}\to\infty\ \ (N\to\infty).$$

Answer (score 6):

The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ is a [$p$-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#P-series) with $p=\frac{1}{2}$. A $p$-series converges when $p < 1$ and diverges when $p \geq 1$.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**

1 / Sqrt[n] is larger than 1 / n. How does behave the sum of 1 / n ?

Answer (score 2):

harmonic series
$$
\sum_1^{N^2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} > 1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \dots + \frac{1}{N}
$$

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM and $n!\lt n^n$, we have $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt k}\gt n\sqrt[n]{\frac{1}{\sqrt{n!}}}\gt\frac{n}{\sqrt[2n]{n!}}\gt\frac{n}{\sqrt n}=\sqrt n.$$ This is quite loose, but elementary and sufficient for divergence.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{1000\sqrt{k}}
&\ge\frac1{500}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}\\
&=\frac1{500}\sum_{k=1}^n(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k})\\[4pt]
&=\frac{\sqrt{n+1}-1}{500}
\end{align}
$$